# How do I resolve the powercfg energy report errors and warnings?

Tags: powercfg, report, energy

I ran the following command from an elevated Command Prompt:

```
powercfg /energy /output "c:\energy.html"
```

The energy report has an error from Realtek and a bunch of warnings.
Are all of these OK to ignore?  If not, how can I resolve them? Here's a screenshot of the report:

[image: Energy Report Screenshot]

Comment: What is it, that people seem to think that a screenshot is a viable way to show text? Don't you like kittens? Pleas see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question (serious link) or https://xkcd.com/2116/ (joke)

Comment: Sorry -- didn't know that.  Now I do.  Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

It depends on your environment, on your computer use, etcetera.

The error (which I cannot cut and paste from your picture)  basically says that your computer will not go into sleep. If you don't use the sleep mode, you can safely ignore the error. Normally, this should perhaps have been a warning too.

Warnings are not errors; in general they tell you that some functionality is missing or that you may expect some abnormal behavior (without the warning it would have been *unexpected* behavior).

Some warnings are for the system, some for the report generation. You seem to have a different timer setting and there were some issues generating the CPU utilization. You also seem to have an old WiFi router, one that doesn't support powersave.

Answer (score 0):

Also try using the command exactly as HELP says:

POWERCFG /ENERGY /OUTPUT "longtrace.html" /DURATION 120

You are missing the Duration parameter.

I get this output:

> Enabling tracing for 120 seconds... Observing system behavior...
> Analyzing trace data... Analysis complete.
>
> Energy efficiency problems were found.
>
> 3 Errors 7 Warnings 28 Informational
>
> See C:\longtrace.html for more details.

I get this output in longtrace:

> Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report Computer Name XXXX Scan
> Time  2021-03-10T17:49:44Z Scan Duration  120 seconds System
> Manufacturer  LENOVO System Product Name  XXXX BIOS Date  11/12/2020 BIOS
> Version   N1FET74W (1.48 ) OS Build   19042 Platform
> Role  PlatformRoleMobile Plugged In   true Process Count  256 Thread
> Count 2613 Report GUID    {1986b545-0768-4151-9880-4fd7ef9cd836} Analysis
> Results Errors Power Policy:802.11 Radio Power Policy is Maximum
> Performance (On Battery) The current power policy for
> 802.11-compatible wireless network adapters is not configured to use low-power modes. Power Policy:Sleep timeout is disabled (Plugged In)
> The computer is not configured to automatically sleep after a period
> of inactivity. CPU Utilization:Processor utilization is high The
> average processor utilization during the trace was high. The system
> will consume less power when the average processor utilization is very
> low. Review processor utilization for individual processes to
> determine which applications and services contribute the most to total
> processor utilization. Average Utilization (%)    22.73

Since my computer is working properly, this output is mostly informational.